# RÓÍSÍN is being rendered as RÃôÃìSÃìN - which encoding is this?

Tags: character-encoding

I have a set of characters in a UTF-8 file like so:

```
RÓÍSÍN 
HÉÁTHÉR
```

The file is being sent to another system, but the characters are being rendered like this:

```
RÃôÃìSÃìN ÃüNDREW
HÃëÃüTHÃëR MULLÃüN
```

Is it possible to tell from this information which character encoding the characters are being rendered as on the remote system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can tell exactly which encoding is being used, but you can tell it is an encoding that uses 1 byte per character. (UTF-8 use 1 to 4)

UTF-8 'Ó' is 0xC3 0x93, which is 195 244 in decimal. ANSI encoding would yield 'Ãô'. This matches your output.